# MYSQL Database query to return highest score

Tags: mysql, database

Hello im working on database for school using mysql. I got stuck on the query to return student with the highest score. I tried different combinations of queries and none of them worked. Some returned all students with grade 100 (note only one of my students have grade 100 in the test data) and other returned First student in test data with grade 100. I suspect there is an error in my database but i cannot solve it.

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
StudentID INT  auto_increment,
ClassID VARCHAR(10),
FirstName VARCHAR(25),
LastName VARCHAR(25),
DateOfBirth DATE,
Gender VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, ClassID)
);

create table Subjects
(
SubjectID INT,
SubjectName VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (SubjectID)
);



create table Grade
(
StudentID INT,
SubjectID INT,
ClassID VARCHAR(10),
Grade DECIMAL(5,1),
FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID),
FOREIGN KEY (SubjectID) REFERENCES Subjects(SubjectID),
FOREIGN KEY (ClassID) REFERENCES Student(ClassID)
);



Test data:
INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, ClassID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Gender)
VALUES ('', '01', 'John', 'Smith', '15/01/2000', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Michael', 'Black', '15/03/2000', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Dennis', 'White', '07/08/1999', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Emy', 'Blue', '10/04/2000', 'Female'),
('', '01', 'Joe', 'Yellow', '09/05/2000', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Aaren', 'Jackson', '09/009/1999', 'Male'),
('', '01', 'Marta', 'Harris', '30/01/2000', 'Female'),
('', '01', 'Laura', 'Lewis', '09/01/2000', 'Female'),
('', '01', 'Michael', 'Jackson', '01/01/2000', 'Male'),

('', '02', 'Piotr', 'Kowalski', '15/01/2000', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Harris', 'Bialy', '15/03/2000', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Porter', 'Czarny', '07/08/1999', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Maciek', 'Blue', '10/04/2000', 'Female'),
('', '02', 'Mateusz', 'Yellow', '09/05/2000', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Aaren', 'Jackson', '09/009/1999', 'Male'),
('', '02', 'Marta', 'Harris', '30/01/2000', 'Female'),
('', '02', 'Laura', 'Lewis', '09/01/2000', 'Female'),
('', '02', 'Chaytan', 'Jackson', '01/01/2000', 'Male');


INSERT INTO Subjects (SubjectID, SubjectName)
VALUES ('01', 'English'),
('02', 'Mathematics'),
('03', 'Science'),
('04', 'Geography'),
('05', 'IT'),
('06', 'History');

INSERT INTO Grade (StudentID, SubjectID, ClassID, Grade)
VALUES ('01', '1', '01', '60.5'),
('01', '2', '01', '70.0'),
('01', '3', '01', '40.0'),
('01', '4', '01', '33.5'),
('01', '5', '01', '90.0'),
('01', '6', '01', '77.5'),
('01', '7', '01', '89.0'),
('01', '8', '01', '74.0'),
('01', '9', '01', '66.5'),

('01', '10', '02', '30.5'),
('01', '11', '02', '50.0'),
('01', '12', '02', '30.0'),
('01', '13', '02', '73.5'),
('01', '14', '02', '70.0'),
('01', '15', '02', '57.5'),
('01', '16', '02', '69.0'),
('01', '17', '02', '34.0'),
('01', '18', '02', '76.5'),

('02', '1', '01', '65.5'),
('02', '2', '01', '73.0'),
('02', '3', '01', '41.0'),
('02', '4', '01', '39.5'),
('02', '5', '01', '96.0'),
('02', '6', '01', '70.5'),
('02', '7', '01', '80.0'),
('02', '8', '01', '74.0'),
('02', '9', '01', '64.5'),

('02', '10', '02', '55.5'),
('02', '11', '02', '43.0'),
('02', '12', '02', '61.0'),
('02', '13', '02', '49.5'),
('02', '14', '02', '76.0'),
('02', '15', '02', '80.5'),
('02', '16', '02', '99.0'),
('02', '17', '02', '100.0'),
('02', '18', '02', '55.5');
```

---

Can you see where have i gone wrong? Could you also tell me appropriate query to retrieve student with highest score. Thanks

Comment: I can see a block of text that I am too lazy to read :) try formatting and summarizing, and showing what you tried

Comment: Great table structure and example data. But where is the query that failed?

Comment: finally: [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86be0)

Comment: students with the highest score for each subjects ? for a subject in particulary ?

Comment: Student with highest score overall and student for a particular class

As i said before I tried so many queries and i didnt note them all.

Comment: there are many errors in your requests for your database creation, did you really achieve to create your database and put some data in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want, this will get you the student with the highest score on each subject, if you want a particular subject, you can change `WHERE SubjectID=Subjects.SubjectID` to `WHERE SubjectID=particular_subject_id`

```
SELECT Student.FirstName, Subjects.SubjectName, Grade.Grade, Subjects.SubjectID FROM 
Student INNER JOIN Grade ON Grade.StudentID=Student.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Subjects ON Grade.SubjectID=Subjects.SubjectID WHERE Grade.Grade=
(SELECT MAX(Grade) FROM Grade WHERE SubjectID=Subjects.SubjectID)
```

For average:

```
 SELECT Subjects.SubjectName, AVG(Grade.Grade), Grade.ClassID, Subjects.SubjectID 
 FROM Grade INNER JOIN Subjects ON Grade.SubjectID=Subjects.SubjectID
 GROUP BY Grade.ClassID, Grade.SubjectID;
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53a4e/8) to see results of highest score and average.

Comment: +1, i used to do `WHERE Grade.Grade IN
(SELECT MAX(Grade) FROM Grade GROUP BY SubjectID)` , is your method better, more efficient ?

Comment: Yes it is faster as it users `=` and no `GROUP BY`... you could always try stuff for yourself, thanks for the +1

Comment: When i test it using your query I get:
5 records of Michael with grades: 65.5 73.0 41.0 39.5 96.0 77.5
and last record of John 77.5

which is obviously wrong...

Comment: @user1800674 Your inserts are inverted in grades, you are inserting the subjectid at the place of studentId and vice versa. I inverted them back in my fiddle, that's why our results are different,notice your subjectid in grades is going up till 18 when you only have 4 subjects

Comment: Thanks it works. However how do I retrieve avg class score? I was unable to work it out this morning

Comment: @user1800674 Update the fiddle and the answer with the avg query. Please mark the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You should try this one as also correct answer:

```
SELECT 
A.FirstName, 
C.SubjectName, 
B.Grade, 
C.SubjectID 
FROM Student AS A
INNER JOIN Grade AS B ON B.StudentID=A.StudentID 
INNER JOIN Subjects AS C ON B.SubjectID=C.SubjectID 
WHERE B.Grade=(SELECT MAX(Grade) FROM Grade WHERE SubjectID=C.SubjectID)
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86be0/10)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your correctly something like this should work:

```
select s.* from Students s
    join Grades g on a.StudentID = s.StudentID
where s.StudentID = (select max(Grade) from Grades);
```