# Fetch highest test score for each subject for selected students in Core Data

Tags: ios, sql, uitableview, core-data

So I have seen example of [how to pull the highest score overall in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262445/mysql-database-query-to-return-highest-score) but would like to do something more complicated in a Core Data Table.

I have a list of athletes who have taken various physical fitness tests. I would like to fetch only the highest "score" and only for the sub-group of students that the user chooses.

I am able to pull the sub-set of students:

```
-(void) setAthleteIDsForPredicate:(NSSet *)athleteIDsForPredicate
{
    _athleteIDsForPredicate = athleteIDsForPredicate;

    [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

and then in my setupFetchedResultsController:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY whoRan.athleteID in %@) AND (eventPR > 0)",
                     self.athleteIDsForPredicate];
```

So this predicate pulls the students in the NSSet and only students who have a score in the event. However it pulls all the scores for the event. I would like to pull only the highest score.

Is there a way to do this using iOS code? Thanks.

[image: Core Data Model]

Comment: Your data model is not clear from your explanation. Are there two entities, `Athlete` and `Event` where `score` is an attribute of `Event`?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I have two entities (See edited question) with a one to many relationship from athletes to Performance Marks (MarksFromMeets). whoRan is the relationship name on the Performance side.

I am pulling records from the MarksFromMeet entity and using the whoRan relationship to only pull records for athletes in my NSSet. I just need to get the Max for sortMark but the Max for EACH athlete not for the athletes overall.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to pull records from the AthleteInfo side. Have never used iteration in a setupFetchRequestController.